# Установка react на проект

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, install

при попытке установить react выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

попытка переустановить node js на 16.15.0 или 18.1.0 не дала успеха. Также решение от сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358643/you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-which-is-behind-the-latest-release-5-0 не помогло.C чем это связанно?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Иван, а у вас установлен create-react-app глобально? Если да, то наверное стоит начать с его удаления. Выполните команду, которую вам подсказывает create-react-app: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` / `yarn global remove create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0):

пробовали эту команду?
`npm install -g create-react-app`

Источник:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

или

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app
```